# How to click on the particular Values Using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This Piece of code working fine. But the problem is it loading all the value from the property file and clicking on the 1st value from the list. If i want to click 5th value from the list how can i do it.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;
try {
    input = new FileInputStream("C:/FilterSection/kpi.properties");
    // load a properties file
    properties.load(input);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
int total = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("total_ids"));
for(int i=1 ; i<= total ; i++){
    String identifier = properties.getProperty("id_"+i);
    System.out.print(identifier);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));
    actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
}
```

But what it is doing from the property file means

```
total_ids=5
id_1=ext-pr-backlog-age
id_2=ext-timetoassign-prs
id_3=ext-timetodeliver-prs
id_4=ext-timetoresolve-prs
id_5=ext-new-prs
```

It is loading and printing all the ids as follows

```
ext-pr-backlog-ageext-timetoassign-prsext-timetodeliver-prsext-timetoresolve-prsext-new-prs
```

for this line `System.out.print(identifier);`

and when I'm using this piece of code

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

It is going and clicking on the 1st kpi only. How can i do any one KPI from the list not only the 1st KPI.

This KPI id_1=ext-pr-backlog-age it is clicking in the FE. but if i want the 5th means how to do it.. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Anyone can reply me soon

Comment: you want to click on  the 5th element is it?

Comment: yes i want to click the 5th element.. could you please give any suggestion.

Comment: If you run this code `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));` out of for loop, by providing the 5th element id does that work?

Comment: Could anyone give me reply. I need to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Use condition to solve this issue. The below piece of code is just an example.

```
for(int i=1 ; i<= total ; i++){
String identifier = properties.getProperty("id_"+i);
System.out.print(identifier);

//You could use an if condition to do it
if(i=5){
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
}
}
```